# How do I say these phrases in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

I don't know Spanish beyond maybe a half a dozen common words.

How do I say these in a casual, unfamiliar tone:

> - Did I get a package from UPS?
> - Sorry, that's all the Spanish I know.

Google Translate shows:

> - ¿Conseguí un paquete de UPS?
> - Lo siento, eso es todo el español que sé.

But I don't particularly trust it, so I wanted to confirm. In particular, Google translates the first back to "I got a UPS package?" which is not the way I would phrase that in English. Also, I'm not sure if "hablo", "entiendo", or "sé" makes more sense in the second phrase.

Comment: As it's written, this question is simply asking for a translation--or verification of an automatic translation. We are not a translation service. It's appropriate to question automatic translations, but try to make your questions here very specific. Is there a particular part of the sentence that seems off to you, that you have reason to doubt?

Comment: @Flimzy Thanks, I'll avoid questions like this in the future. I didn't have a specific reason for doubting the automatic translation other than not being clear on which verb to use in the second phrase.

Comment: We want to focus on questions that help you gain a better understanding of the Spanish language.  Using Google Translate as a starting point often makes good sense, but the questions need to be directed in such a way that you will gain a better understanding--not just a "correct translation." I hope that makes sense. :) And welcome to the site!

Comment: "Conseguí" is not the word I'd use in this context. May "obtenir" or "recibir." (I'm not a native speaker, however.) If you edited your question to ask about this, or similar word choice, you might be able to get it re-opened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the most casual way would be for `Did I get a package from UPS?`like this :

- *¿Me llegó un paquete de UPS?*

And for this `Sorry, that's all the Spanish I know.`

- *Lo siento (o Disculpa) es todo el español que sé.*

If you're talking about making a conversation with another person you should use *sé*, because that means you don't know how to speak or understanding what you're listening, if  you're just talking, you should use *hablo* and if you're listening or reading you should use *entiendo*.

Comment: Thanks; it seems hard to find a 100% perfect rule of thumb for "lo siento" vs. "disculpa". "Lo siento" seems to be the right choice based on what I'm reading for a genuine "I am sorry" (although really the situation is kind of humorous). Really what this all boils down to is yet another case for me to seriously start learning Spanish (if I can convince a 32 year old brain to take on a second language)...

Comment: @JasonC, `disculpa`, `perdona` o `lo siento` are in most contexts equivalent. Don't try to always speak perfectly, you'll burn out, and people will understand you anyway.

Comment: Well, I got my package, and I didn't even have to use the second phrase. Mission accomplished!